# Connecting to Snowflake using key-pair stored in Azure Key Vault, from Java/Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-keyvault

just need clarification on the process to take if I need to authenticate using **key-pair** to **Snowflake**, and **private key** is stored in **Azure Key Vault**? How should the private key be installed in Azure Key Vault?
Is it really needed to contact Snowflake Support to complete that kind of security configuration, or all could be done from a Java client side? This is using **Java/SpringBoot**. Thanks in advance! :)